# What would be a cool azure app?

Tags: azure

I was on MSDN live a couple of days ago and on one of the stands they had this competition: Write the coolest azure app within a couple of months and win a Windows 7 Ultimate. Great, I would like to try out some azure programming, but it got me thinking, how would a azure app stand out from normal web apps. Basically it is just the hardware that's different, but it forces you to write your app somewhat different.

What are some examples of cool apps that clearly is easier and better suited as a cloud app than on a normal web app?

Answer (score 7):

Make an app that automatically deposits funds in my financial accounts when run.  Now THAT would be cool :)

Comment: ...and Apple.  Think there's a direct link from my wallet into Steve Jobs' wallet.

Answer (score 2):

**Network file system / Sharing**

Mount it like a drive in windows.  Use it from a web browser anywhere.  Be sure to include twitter integration ;)

Comment: Definitely an option but I guess it would be pretty expensive though

Answer (score 1):

File hosting/CDN

Perfectly suited for cloud deployment

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the Azure service management API so that an Azure app could scale itself and tie itself to a bank account.  Develop an app "AI" so that it could completely support itself independently of a human.

Answer (score 1):

This would be certainly cool.

Write a analytics reporting tool (something like google analytics for websites) using Azure APIs that would report the various statistics related to the application deployed on Azure cloud.

Answer (score 1):

[Swingify](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/making-songs-swing-with-windows-azure-python-and-the-echo-nest-api): an app that lets you upload MP3 files and will convert the song to swing time.

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/making-songs-swing-with-windows-azure-python-and-the-echo-nest-api

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that anyone can all of a sudden make something cool on Azure, which they couldn't make themselves with a hosting provider themselves.

Answer (score 0):

We are working on this app. Give it a look http://www.blockmonster.eu.